# SqlAlchemy: Joined tables in case expression

Tags: sqlalchemy, case

I have a hybrid property and an expression for it like:

```
  @ans_score.expression
    def ans_score(cls):
        return case(
        [
            (
                and_(cls.question.anstype == AnsTEnum.yesno, 
                     cls.yesno == Questions.yesno), Questions.max_score
            )
         ], else_=0)
```

However, `cls.question` is a relationship and I get

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with QuestionUser.question has an attribute 'anstype'
```

I can change it to `Questions.anstype`, however, then I don't know how to join my table (`QuestionUser`) with `Questions` table

Answer (score 0):

I could put the expression in a `select` and then `select_from` joined tables.

I solved it using:

```
return select(
    case([
            (
                and_(cls.question.anstype == AnsTEnum.yesno, 
                     cls.yesno == Questions.yesno), Questions.max_score
            )
         ],
         else_=0)
).select_from(QuestionUser).where(Questions.id == cls.qid)
```